# Wpf binded property not updating in 2-way-mode

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have simple gallery with notes and text box to add new one by title.
I use mvvm, other bindings work correcty.
When I set title of note and click add property NewNote.Title is updated and object saved in database. After that I clear NewNote.Title but UI is not updated.

here is short video https://youtu.be/l3vFwI-a4TQ

xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewNote.Title}" />
```

page view model

```
class NotesPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<NoteViewModel> Notes { get; set; }
    public NoteViewModel NewNote { get; set; }

    public NotesPageViewModel()
    {
        NewNote = new NoteViewModel();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    internal void LoadNotes()
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            Notes.Clear();
            uow.NotesRepository.OrderBy(n => n.Position).ToList()
                .ForEach(note => Notes.Add((NoteViewModel)note));
        }
    }

    internal void AddNote()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NewNote.Title))
            return;

        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            uow.NotesRepository.Add((Note)NewNote);
            uow.Complete();
        }
        NewNote.Title = "";
        LoadNotes();
    }
}
```

object view model

```
class NoteViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the OnPropertyChanged on the viewmodel when you're setting the property

```
class NoteViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    private string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Also, the LoadNotes and AddNotes should be called via a command, and the new title should be sent as a parameter.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have just found fantastic library, I can just place [ImplementPropertyChanged] over class declaration it is called Fody